# How to properly define a derived unit in Boost Unit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-units

I am trying to create a `derived_dimension` in `boost::units` for mass flow rate for `si` system. I cannot find any documentation on how to do this simple task. This is what I have so far but I am getting errors during the compilation.

```
typedef boost::units::derived_dimension<
boost::units::mass_base_dimension, 3,
boost::units::time_base_dimension, -1
>::type mass_flow_rate_dimension;

typedef boost::units::unit<
mass_flow_rate_dimension,
boost::units::si::system
> mass_flow_rate_unit;

typedef boost::units::quantity<mass_flow_rate_unit, double> mass_flow_rate;

BOOST_UNITS_STATIC_CONSTANT(kilogram_per_seconds, mass_flow_rate);
```

This is how I get the error:

```
mass_flow_rate MFR;
quantity<mass_density> density = 1.0 * kilogram_per_cubic_meter;
quantity<si::time> Time = 1.0 * second;
quantity<volume> vol = 1.0 * cubic_meters;
MFR = density * vol / Time;
```

error: C2338 (is_simply_convertible::value == true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mass_flow_rate_dimension` has the wrong dimensions. You have mass to the third instead of just mass

```
typedef boost::units::derived_dimension<
boost::units::mass_base_dimension, 1,
boost::units::time_base_dimension, -1
>::type mass_flow_rate_dimension;
```

Fixes it. That error is meant just for the case when your dimensions don't line up.